# Should I make sure an object is unusable after Dispose was called?

Tags: c#, idisposable

I have a class `BleScanner` that wraps an internal `BluetoothLEAdvertisementWatcher`. It also implements `IDisposable` to make sure that the watcher is stopped when the scanner gets disposed of.

```
public sealed class BleScanner : IDisposable
{
    public event AdvertisementReceivedHandler? AdvertisementReceived;

    private readonly BluetoothLEAdvertisementWatcher m_Watcher;

    public BleScanner() {
        m_Watcher = new() {
            // ...
        };
        // m_Watcher.Received += OnAdvertisementReceived;
    }

    // private void OnAdvertisementReceived(...) {
    //    code elided for brevity
    //    may eventually raise AdvertisementReceived
    // }

    public void Start() => m_Watcher.Start();

    public void Stop() => m_Watcher.Stop();

    public void Dispose() {
        if (m_Watcher.Status == BluetoothLEAdvertisementWatcherStatus.Started) {
            m_Watcher.Stop();
        }
    }
}
```

The watcher is not disposable. So in theory, the scanner would still work if you just called `Start` again after `Dispose`:

```
public async Task ScannerTest(CancellationToken token) {
    using var scanner = new BleScanner();
    scanner.AdvertisementReceived += OnAdvertisementReceived;

    scanner.Start(); // will start the scan
    await Task.Delay(3000, token); // raise events for 3 seconds
    scanner.Stop(); // could be forgotten
    scanner.Dispose(); // will stop the scan if indeed it was forgotten
    
    scanner.Start(); // everything will work, despite "scanner" being disposed already
}
```

Should I make sure `Start` (and maybe `Stop`) throws an `ObjectDisposedException` after `Dispose` was called? The [guidelines on the Dispose pattern](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/standard/garbage-collection/implementing-dispose) only require that `Dispose` can be called multiple times without an exception, but don't say anything about how the other members should behave after `Dispose` was called. Neither does [using disposable objects](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/standard/garbage-collection/using-objects) of the [IDisposable interface](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.idisposable) say what to expect when calling methods on a disposed object.

Comment: _"The watcher is not disposable"_ - so why is your class `IDisposable`? - _"It also implements IDisposable to make sure that the watcher is stopped when the scanner gets disposed of."_ - that is not a good reason to implement `IDisposable`, imo. I can't make any better suggestions though, as unfortunately C# does not (yet) support Linear Types.

Comment: Opinions probably vary, but to me if your instance isn't holding on to disposable objects, then you're kind of imposing an artificial constraint on the class' consumers.

Comment: But to answer the question, IMO if it says `IDisposable` on the tin, then I would _expect_ `ObjectDisposedException` if it's used post-disposal.

Comment: @Dai But why should the watcher keep occupying a time slot on the BLE antenna for scanning if nobody wants to use the results anymore?

Comment: @LWChris I am in agreement with you: it shouldn't - but that's not my point. My point is that I don't think `IDisposable` is necessarily the _best_ way to communicate that _contract requirement_ to your library's consumers. Perhaps if you shared some example use-cases for your `class BleScanner` we could come up with some better suggestions. (For example, short-lived monadic behaviour can be better represented by a `Task` (or `Task<T>` if it has a meaningful result) (which does _not_ imply nor require any use of the `async` modifier BTW).

Comment: @Dai Boils down to - "is slot time in a BLE scheduler an unmanaged resource?" Because if it is, then IDisposable is explicitly there to free unmanaged resources. If it isn't (and maybe the fact that the watcher isn't Disposable itself suggests that), then yes, IDisposable is maybe out of place (although like you, I have no better idea either).

Comment: Is your intent to have consumers scan until the first advertisement is read and then stop?

Comment: Report incorrect usage of your class with InvalidOperationException.

Comment: @HansPassant Exceptions should not be the primary way to communicate contract violations though.

Comment: @Dai is there another way to report contract violation to user of your api?

Comment: @Evk by making it impossible to violate the contract in the first place - that’s the principe behind predicate-types, for example.

Comment: @Dai The scanner can be used to scan for devices until stopped. I don't know why he would scan or why it should be stopped. It might be that it's used for discovery, then the user might stop when the device has been seen. Might be used to create a live list of available devices including their signal strength and scan "forever".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's totally fine to use `IDisposable` to free managed resources, which is really *any* kind of scope that requires code to be run at the end of that scope.

In this case, I would say that the scope is really around `Start` and `Stop`. So I would have `Start` return an `IDisposable` that calls `Stop` (and make `Stop` private). Your type would not be disposable. E.g., using `Disposable` from my Nito.Disposables library:

```
public sealed class BleScanner
{
    public event AdvertisementReceivedHandler? AdvertisementReceived;

    private readonly BluetoothLEAdvertisementWatcher m_Watcher;

    public BleScanner() {
        m_Watcher = new() {
            // ...
        };
        // m_Watcher.Received += OnAdvertisementReceived;
    }

    public IDisposable Start()
    {
        m_Watcher.Start();
        return Disposable.Create(() => Stop());
    }

    private void Stop() => m_Watcher.Stop();
}

public async Task ScannerTest(CancellationToken token) {
    var scanner = new BleScanner();
    scanner.AdvertisementReceived += OnAdvertisementReceived;

    using var scannerSubsctiption = scanner.Start();
    await Task.Delay(3000, token); // raise events for 3 seconds
}
```

Comment: That is somewhat closer to one of my earlier drafts for BleScanner. It was a static class (basically a factory for scans) and you would either call "InfiniteScan" and got an object that had a "Start" and "Stop" and the event to subscribe to, or "TimedScan" with a `TimeSpan` and that had the even and a `Task Run(CancellationToken)` method where the Task would finish after the timeout. But then I figured if I may have multiple watchers, then why not multiple scanners? This one's in the middle, multiple scanners, and basically the "Start" is the disposable thing.

Answer (score 2):

In your question, you reference the [IDisposable Guidelines](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/garbage-collection/implementing-dispose). The first line says "Implementing the Dispose method is primarily for releasing unmanaged resources." I don't think that's what you're doing here. If `BluetoothLEAdvertisementWatcher` was IDisposable, then you could dispose of it in your Dispose() function; but that isn't the case. So, garbage collection will take care of your object in its sweet time after your object falls out of scope; just let it do its thing.

Hope that helps.

Comment: I've recently done a lot of embedded programming, and learned to value resources like radio time. Scanning for BLE devices occupies a significant portion of the BLE round-robin communication time slots, therefore I see that timeslot as an unmanaged resource and want to make sure there's not a rogue scanner left-over eating up BLE performance until finally the GC comes or the program dies of old age.